# JsonBackReference not working as expected

Tags: json, spring, rest, recursion

I have the next two clases...

Class A

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ClassA")
public class ClassA 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="classA")
    private List<ClassB> classBList;
}
```

Class B

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ClassB")
public class ClassB 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ClassAId", nullable = false)
    private ClassA classA;  
}
```

When i do a get of all ClassA records from database using REST the result is working like charm:

GET http://localhost:8080/REST/ClassA

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "VVVV I",
    "classB": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "SSSS I"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "QQQQ II",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "RRRR II",
    "classB": []
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "FFFFF III",
    "classB": []
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "QWERR",
    "classB": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "GGGG III",
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "HHHH IV",
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "JJJJ V",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "TRRR",
    "classB": []
}
]
```

The problem is when i want to get the list of ClassB, the ClassA is not returning at all...

GET http://localhost:8080/REST/ClassB

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "SSSS I"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "QQQQ II"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "GGGG III"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "HHHH IV"
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "JJJJ V"
}
]
```

I need ClassA (without classB inside of it) be listed when getting list of ClassB

How can i achieve that?

Best regards